# OpenVino Optimised model ignores few labels while inferencing

Tags: python, openvino

## System information

- **OpenVINO => 2022.1**
- **Operating System / Platform =>Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-9400F CPU @ 2.90GHz/ Windows 10 64 Bit**

I trained the following YoloV5 model:

- `Model Size: Large`
- `Labels: ['mango', 'apple', 'milk', 'orange', 'grapes']`.
- `batch-size: 4`
- `Img-Size: 512`

When I perform the inference on the trained YoloV5 Model the detections are descent and it is able to detect all 5 labels. The detection confidence is also good averaging around 90%.

I then optimized the model using OpenVino:

- `Quantization: FP16, FP32`

But the converted model only detects `mango, apple, and grapes` and completely ignores the remaining labels.

Things I have tried:

- Retraining the Yolov5 model with different batch-size.
- Tried different quantization while converting to OpenVino.
- Tried different (previous) versions of OpenVino like `2020.4`.

I have previously faced similar issues while training other models but could never figure out the solution or even the cause of the same. Has anyone else faced similar issues?

It would be ideal if someone can guide me in a direction to help solve it. Other answers that also explain potential causes of the issue are also welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Converting the model into a smaller precision has its pros and cons.
The inferencing time is faster but the trade-off is accuracy.

If your use case involves something like clinical results that require to be accurate, it is not recommended to use smaller precision as you need to bear with less accuracy. Meanwhile, if your use case needs to be fast without being precise, then smaller precision (FP16/INT8) is suitable.

You should carefully [choose the right precision](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/should-i-choose-fp16-or-fp32-for-my-deep-learning-model.html) depending on your use case and also hardware.
[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RF8ypHyiKrY) might help you to further understand.